# Write with quantifiers P and ¬P

Tags: quantifiers

Let P: "for all natural $n$, exists an integer $p$ such that $n<p<2n$ "

---

**P**: $\forall\,  n \in \mathbb{N}\,  ||\, \exists \, p\in\mathbb {Z} \, ||\, n<p<2n $

**¬P:** $\exists\, n \in \mathbb{N}\,  ||\, \forall \, p\in\mathbb {Z} \, ||\, n>p>2n $

Is correct the translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. The negation of $n<p<2n$ should be $p\le n$ or $p \ge 2n$.

Comment: Thank you then ¬P is true right?

Comment: With that correction, it will be correct.